# A contradiction in one sample t-test?

Tags: r, t-test

I want to do one sample `t.test` with data

```r
x = c(1450,1480,1640,1610,1500,1600,1420,1530,1700,1550)
```

to see whether `μ=E(x)` is significantly greater than 1600 under level `α=0.01`.

Firstly, I do the normal test for `x`

```r
shapiro.test(x) #p-value = 0.9494
```

Then I have two hypotheses (candidate choices)

```
(case1: right) H0: μ<=1600 <---> H1: μ>1600
(case2: left)  H0: μ>=1600 <---> H1: μ<1600
```

and

```r
m = 1600; alpha = 0.01
t1 = t.test(x, mu=m, alternative="greater", conf.level=1-alpha) #case1: right
t1 #p-value = 0.9511

t2 = t.test(x, mu=m, alternative="less", conf.level=1-alpha) #case2: left
t2 #p-value = 0.04893
```

give contradicted results since both cases don't refuse `H0`! How can I decide which correct (or proper to be exact) one to choose?

Comment: Why is this contradictory? The results tell you that the mean is significantly smaller than 1600, so it cannot be significantly greater than 1600 at the same time? What even is your goal here? Are you trying to do a two-sided test?

Comment: @user2974951 My goal is **to see whether μ=E(x) is significantly greater than 1600 under level α=0.01**. If I choose  `(case1: right) ` than the p value suggests `no`, while the p value of `(case2: left) ` suggests `yes`.

Comment: Ah, I see. These two hypotheses do not answer the same question, they do not cover the same interval. What is 1-0.9511?

Comment: You probably do not have enough samples to test with a significance  level of $\alpha = 0.01$. The power of your test is probably to low and you see if you increase the significance level to $0.05$, then you reject H0 in case 2.

Comment: @lulufofo Make sense! Next maybe I should try to do the power analysis for the two cases, since α just controls the type I error. The power analysis tells us about the type II error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the power of the test, did you understand why they are different?

Comment: @JohnStone "My goal is to see whether μ=E(x) is significantly greater than 1600 under level α=0.01. If I choose (case1: right) than the p value suggests no, while the p value of (case2: left) suggests yes." The p-value of (case2: left) doesn't suggest any such thing. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My goal is to see whether $\mu=E(x)$ is significantly greater than 1600 under level $\alpha=0.01$.

This is misuse of terminology. The term "significant" refers to the relation of the observed data to a null hypothesis, it does *not* refer to the true underlying parameter. You can say that you want to see *whether there is significant evidence* that $\mu>1600$.

In this case you need the test with `alternative="greater"`. This gives you $p=0.9511$, so there is no evidence that $\mu>1600$ (this shouldn't surprise you as the mean of the observed data is in fact smaller than 1600).

The test with  `alternative="less"` tests whether there is evidence that $\mu<1600$. The evidence is significant at 5% level, but not at 1%-level, meaning that you could take the data as giving some moderate indication that $\mu<1600$ but not strong. Note however that if you run two tests, the chance that at least one of them gives $p<0.05$ even if the null hypothesis is true is *larger* than 0.05 (standard issue with multiple testing), and if you're interested in testing $\mu=1600$ against both $\mu>1600$ and $\mu<1600$, you should use a two-sided test rather than running one-sided tests against both alternatives separately. The two-sided test will be insignificant even at 5%-level.

Note also that generally not rejecting a null hypothesis doesn't mean that the null hypothesis is true; it just means that based on the limited amount of data you have, the observations are not clearly incompatible with the null hypothesis. so at 1% level you can't rule out that $\mu=1600$, and in fact it may also be smaller or (a bit) larger; your data imply that you can't know for sure. Had you *only* be interested in the alternative $\mu<1600$, the test with `alternative="less"` would've provided some indication that $\mu$ is not $\ge 1600$, but if in fact in advance you thought "if anything, $\mu$ will be larger than 1600, not smaller", a two-sided test doesn't indicate $\mu\neq 1600$ at 5% level, so 1600 is still compatible with the data, as are in all likelihood 1599 and 1601 and other values north and south of 1600 (you could compute a confidence interval to find out more precisely).

Comment: Tks for your detailed reply. Although I am still a little bit confused, I try my best to understand it. Eventually, I choose the  `case2(left)` one as the hypothesis for given data to my concern, since `case2(left)`  has higher power (i.e., lower typer II error )than `case1(right)`. @christian-hennig

Comment: @JohnStone Why would you think that ````case2(left)```` has higher power?

Comment: Try `?pwr::pwr.t.test`  in R? @christian-hennig

Comment: I understand that the points one should supply more data or give a higher α. I just wander that whether we can make as proper as possible conclusion under given (limited) data. Since α controls the upper bound for type I errors of the  hypotheses, it is natural to consider the lower one for the type II error.

Comment: @JohnStone Power analyses are correctly done before collecting the data. Chances are you have applied ````pwr.t.test```` plugging in the observed mean value, and the mean is smaller than your H0, so any power will be on that side. But this is not how power should be used; note in particular that the estimated mean is not the true one, and that if the true one happens to be larger than 1600 (as hypothesised by you in a comment, and not contradicted by the data), ````alternative="greater"```` will have the larger power.

Comment: @JohnStone Valid hypothesis testing will fix the test before seeing the data; if you decide which test you use based on the data, you invalidate your test. Also given limited data absolutely a proper conclusion can be that we can't rule out $\mu=1600$, and neither that true $\mu$ is smaller nor larger. The best thing you could do in my view is to compute a confidence interval to see the range of values of $\mu$ compatible with the data.

Comment: Very appreciate! @christian-hennig